# How to find the x coordinate of the maximum of |f(x)|

Tags: functions, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I have the following function:

$$
 f(x) = {\sin{x}\over a + \cos{x}}
$$

I have found that this function has a maximum
$$ f_\mathrm{max} = \arctan{\left(1\over\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\right)}$$ at $x = \arccos{\left(-{1\over a}\right)}$.

However, I am considering now the function:

$$
g(x) = |f(x) + b|
$$

And I am trying to find the maximum value of $g(x)$ and its corresponding $x$ value.

Using the graph of the function, I can see that:

$$
g_\mathrm{max} = f_\mathrm{max} + |b|
$$

But this time, the $x$ coordinate of the $g_\mathrm{max}$ will depend on the sign of $b$. That is:

- if $b \geq 0$ then $g_\mathrm{max}$ occurs at:
  $x = \arccos{\left(-{1\over a}\right)}$
- if $b < 0$ then $g_\mathrm{max}$ occurs at
  $x = 2\pi - \arccos{\left(-{1\over a}\right)}$

**My question:**

Is it possible to express the last two conditions into a single formula? in other words, is there a **single** formula for $x$ coordinate of $g_\mathrm{max}$ ?

Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: @Pierre: How do I consider $x\in[0,2\pi]$? as far as I know, only `arctan2(y,x)` function can take care of that.